# IBM ThinkPad t410s - making copy of backup partition to recover disk space

Tags: hard-drive, backup

I see the forum.  I bought the laptop used.  The original buyer must have made a backup copy, or it wouldn't reject my doing so, now.  I need the disk space.  The IBM link for requesting the backup is useless--including its menu's only offering XP and nothing newer.  Not paranoia: just don't want to throw away the original system bkup in order to reclaim disk space.  Thoughts?  Thanks.

Comment: What program was used to make the backup?

Answer (score 1):

You could clone the existing disk to an image so that if you ever need to restore it you can restore it from that.

Other options could include purchasing the Ultrabay kit with a hard disk supported by your laptop and

1) replacing the optical drive and use that for the extra storage.

or

2) clone your existing disk to the ultrabay hdd (assuming larger capactity disk) then move the new disk into the existing hdd slot (make sure the replacement disk is of the correct height as a model with a smaller height won't fit in the original hdd slot. THen you can extend the new disk using your preferred disk management tool and decide whether to keep the old disk for storage or put the optical drive back in.